# The Discrete Metric

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

I feel rather embarrassed and ashamed asking this question , since it is so obvious.

Anyway here I go...

I am trying to proof rigorously that the Discrete Metric ,  which is defined as:
$$ d_D(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x =y \\ 1 & x\neq y \end{cases}$$  is a metric on any set $X$

In particular show that it satisfies the  following condition:

$$d(x ,y) = 0 \iff x =y  $$

**My Attempt:**

If $x =y$ then by definition of $d_D(x,y) =0$

Now suppose that $d_D(x,y) =0$ but $x\neq y$. Then by definition  $d_D(x,y) =1$.

We have a contradiction so there if $d_D(x ,y) =0$ then $x=y$

Is this rigorous enough?

Comment: Yes, but slightly overcomplicated. Just say "If $x=y$, by definition $d_D(x,y) = 0$. If $x \neq y$, by definition $d_D(x,y) = 1 \neq 0$".

Comment: @fgp $d_D(y,x) = \begin{cases} 0 & y=x \\ 1 & y \neq x \end{cases} =  \begin{cases} 0 & x =y \\ 1 & x \neq y \end{cases} = d_D(x,y)$  Is this a valid proof of symmetry?

Comment: Yes. In this case, my personal preference would be to write this as "Let $x,y \in X$. If $x=y$, then trivially $d_D(x,y)=d_D(y,x)$. If $x \neq y$ then $d_D(x,y) = 1 = d_D(y,x)$." But your way of writing this is fine too.